# Google Maps API v3 - Adding Event Listeners inside 'for' loop only works in some iterations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a website using Google Maps API v3. The basic funcionality that is important for this matter is the following:

- from a JS array, read coordinates of several points (working)
- create the markers on the map (working)
- add an event listener for click event to each marker (only works for some iterations of the loop)

JS array marker information example:

```
var photos = [
{
    file: "republica87",
    title: "Av. República, 87",
    yearA: "2013",
    yearB: "1909",
    desc: "Edifício típico ...",
    author: "Paulo Guedes",
    from: "Arquivo Municipal de Lisboa | Fotográfico",
    link: "...", 
    coords: "38.74266,-9.146851,-85",
},

/*...*/

];
```

For the markers, only the `coords` field is relevant, which is then split into latitude and longitude (the third value does not matter for this).

Then, inside a 'for' loop, the markers are created and a 'click' event listener is created as well, for each marker:

```
/*...*/

var markercam=new Array();

for (var i=1;i<photos.length;i++){
    coords=photos[i].coords;
    coords=coords.split(",");
    lat=coords[0];
    lon=coords[1];
    rot=coords[2];

    /*...*/

    markercam[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        map: map,
        icon: cameraicon,
        url: './galeria.html?id='+i,
        indice: i,
        shape: shapecirc,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markercam[i], 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = this.url;    
    });

    /*...*/

}

/*...*/
```

However, it seems that the Listener is only added for some of the markers. I have not figured out anything about those markers that may be causing this. For reference, the values of `i` that do create the Listener are: 1, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 22. They are always the same.

It's also important to note that, besides the 'click' Listener, I have also added 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' events, that work for every marker with no issues.

The file that has all the marker information is <strike>here</strike>, and the map where the markers are placed is <strike>here</strike>. As you can see, when clicking on *some* markers, you are sent to a different page, whereas others don't do anything. Example: the southernmost marker works, the northernmost doesn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

PS: Please excuse any obvious programming problems, this is the first time I am dealing with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented(at least I couldn't find it), but setting the `optimized`-property of the markers to `false` fixes it for me.

As it seems the call of `setZIndex()` will update the `ZIndex` of the Marker-Image, but not the `ZIndex` of the MouseTarget(the clickable region, it's defined in a different layer) , when the `optimized`-property is set to `true`(the default-setting)